# Partition of the set of n-digit binary sequence

Tags: combinatorics

An $n$-digit binary sequence is an $n$-tuple of the form $(a_1, \ldots, a_n)$ in which each  $a_i$ is $0$ or $1$. Two such sequences are *neighbours* if they differ in exactly one position; more precisely, given two $n$-digit binary sequences $a=(a_1, \ldots, a_n)$ and $a'=(a'_1, \ldots, a'_n)$, we say that $a$ and $a'$ are neighbours if there is exactly one $i$ such that $a_i\neq a'_i$.

My question is: For which positive integers $n$ can one partition the set of the $2^n$ $n$-digit binary sequences into $n$ sets so that, for any $n$-digit binary sequence, no two of its $n$ neighbours are in the same set?

I found an interesting way to make the partition for $n=2^k$, $k$ positive integer. I don't know whether such partitions exist for other values of $n$.

Answer (score 1):

With no additional limitations the problem seems trivial (unless I am misreading it). Notice that neighbours must have different parity. Therefore you can partition sequences into 2 sets, one with odd parity, and another with even. No 2 neighbours would belong to the same set. For example ($n = 3$),

$ \{ 000, 011, 101, 110\} $ (even parity) and

$ \{001, 010, 100, 111 \}$ (odd parity).

From there, you can arbitrary subdivide them to achieve a desired numbers of sets.

Comment: I think you indeed misread it. The partition must be such that, given any $n$-digit binary sequence, each of its $n$ neighbours is in a different set. For $n=3$, for example, take the sequence $(1, 0, 1)$. No two of its neighbours ($(0, 0, 1)$, $(1, 1, 1)$, $(1, 0, 0)$) can be in the same set of the partition. I've edited the original post in order to make this condition more clear.
Note that it is trivially impossible two perform such a partition into less than $n$ sets. The question is to determine those integers $n$ for which such a partition exists into exactly $n$ sets.